# Xpath Localisation

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I am stuck on a Xpath expression ..
Can you help me to find the Xpath to get "Entry" Element like "SecSE" please ?
I would like to get the itemName attribute content too :)

Thank you very much

Here is my XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <MLiveDataLog>
  <ControllerPath>Controller</ControllerPath>
  <description>Autogenerated XML export file</description>
  <Log xmlns="http://iec.ch/61400/ews/1.0/">
       <LogName>AllLiveData</LogName>
     <Entry tabName="Test" itemName="Turbine" aggregation="2" description="">
       <TimeOfEntry>
         <SecSE>1427199750</SecSE>
         <Tq>
           <LSK>false</LSK>
         </Tq>
       </TimeOfEntry>
     </Entry>
  </Log>
</MLiveDataLog>
```

I use ruby with Nokogiri like this :

```
require 'nokogiri'


    doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("test.xml"))
    puts doc.xpath("/MLiveDataLog/Log/Entry/@itemName")
```

It seems like I cannot access under the "Log" element

Comment: That is because there is a default namespace declared at `Log`. Find out a way to add that namespace to `Log` and `Entry` in your xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts your input document are in a *default namespace*:

```
<Log xmlns="http://iec.ch/61400/ews/1.0/">
```

The `Log` element and all its descendant elements are in that namespace, and the namespace is part of the identity of those elements. That is, `Log` and `{http://iec.ch/61400/ews/1.0/}Log` are very different elements.

Namespaces absolutely need to be taken into account in XPath expressions. In your code, you need to declare this namespace together with a *prefix* - and prefix all element names that are in namespaces.

Nokogiri tries to be helpful by simply [redeclaring any namespace declarations found on the *root* of the document](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html) - but, as you can see, in your case the declaration is not on the outermost element.

```
require "nokogiri"

@doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read("mlive.xml"))
puts @doc.xpath('/MLiveDataLog/iec:Log/iec:Entry/@itemName', 'iec' => 'http://iec.ch/61400/ews/1.0/')
```

and the result will be

```
Turbine
```